# Conflict between eRPC and usb msd due to USE_SHMEM

Tags: c, shared-memory, rpc, azure-rtos

I have an i.MX RT1160 Evaluation Kit.

1. On CM7, I have:

- Azure RTOS (ThreadX, FileX, UsbX)
- eRPC

2. on Cm4: Bare Metal and eRPC.

It seems that I need the preprocessor USE_SHMEM for eRPC.

When I add the preprocessor USE_SHMEM, eRPC is working but UsbX is not working as I want. Basicall, my usd mass storage device (msd) does not appear anymore in my Windows Explorateur.

If I remove the preprocessor USE_SHMEM, UsbX is working as expected but this time eRPC is not working any more.

Maybe the problem is how the memory allocation are defined. Please find attached the memory allocation.

[Linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wndDe.png)

[Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GErL.png)

Could you help me to solve this issue? I would like to have both eRPC and usb msd working at the same time.